# Why I should use JavaScript for page validation, even I can use php for same work?

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I m beginner to learn java script and I just read that we use java script for interactive and page validation ...so my question is that

We can validate our page with the help of php then why we should use JavaScript?

Answer (score 7):

Ideally, you should be doing both. But at the least, you should be using server side validation.

The reason you have JS or client side validation is so that

1. The user gets immediate feedback on errors
2. Your server is spared the round trip for smaller validation

You should never rely only on JS for validation as this can be easily disabled/circumvented. Always use it as an added layer to your server side validation.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript validation allows a more 'responsive' validation message since it doesn't require a postback.

However you should always include server side validation AS WELL since a user could turn off javascript and bypass the validation.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript vaidation is client side validation. You do it even before your page is submitted to the server. And hence prevent resubmitting your page all again

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is used for browser side validation i.e, client side , But php is used for ser

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean that you can validate the data entered at the server end in php and you do not see the point in validating at the client side using Javascript.

Javascript runs on the client (i.e. the user's browser), which means the data does not have to make a round trip to the server to be validated. This makes the process faster and reduces load on the server. Imagine someone entering a huge amount of data into a text field that is supposed to accept only 15 characters. If you validate only in the server side, your application stalls while the data is being sent. If you also validate using Javascript, nothing is sent back since it is caught at the user's browser.

That being said, it is a good idea to validate at *both* the client and the server. This takes care of someone intentionally circumventing your Javascript validation (e.g. by turning off Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

These are the two sides of a coin:

**PHP = Server Side vs Javascript = Client Side**

Both operate in different mediums on opposite sides of the HTTP fence

*You can't really compare them. Normally, you use them both. Javascript for the nice dynamic client side stuff (like hiding a part of the page) and PHP to generate the page. And then there's ajax, which makes both work really great together.*

**Some more comparision:**

In php you can have the remote and local time

In js you can have user time...

---

In php you can have remote and host address

In js ... i dont know !!

---

In php the source is not lookable in the source code

In js the source can be see in the source code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

To use php it requires sending a request to the php and getting a response.

Javascript is client-side therefore eliminates the need for the request to be send.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a much faster way since you do not need to send a request to the server.

But it depends if you are validating a form with certain data that you need checked.

For example, if you have a form and there is an email input box, you may want to check if that email is already in your database. This would require php.

Otherwise, if you do not need to make a request to your server, javascript would be the better one to use.